# Can't find a way to refactor alert (exercise)

Tags: javascript, scope, refactoring

I'm a JS noob trying to make this "hello mr./miss *yourname*!" clean.
I don't see a way to refactor the alert inside the if/else because then i lose the value of var b.

the JS:

```
<script>
    "use strict";
    window.onload = function () {
        let form1 = document.getElementById('myForm');
        form1.addEventListener('submit', helloYou);
        function helloYou() {
            let x = document.getElementById("1").value; 
            let a = document.getElementById('3').value;
            if ( a === "M") {
                let b = "Mr.";
                alert('Hello ' + b + " " + x + "!");
            }
            else {
                let b = "Miss";
                alert('Hello ' + b + " " + x + "!");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

the HTML:

```
<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        Write your name:
        <input type="text" name="yourname" id="1" placeholder="name">
        <select name="gender" id="3">
            <option value="M">Male</option>
            <option value="F">Female</option>
        <input type="submit" name="submission" id="2" value="TRY ME">
    </form>
</body>
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: As a side note (as you mention you're refactoring), you should give your variables and IDs better names - `a`, `b`, `x`, `1`, `2` and `3` aren't descriptive!  You can also use `const` instead of `let`.

Comment: Yes i know, but those are just little standalone exercises so the context is really little. I wouldn't do the same in a longer code. But thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use *ternary operator*

```
alert('Hello ' + ( a === "M" ? "Mr." : "Miss" ) + " " + x + "!");
```

i.e.

```
   function helloYou() {
        let x = document.getElementById("1").value; 
        let a = document.getElementById('3').value;
        alert('Hello ' + ( a === "M" ? "Mr." : "Miss" ) + " " + x + "!");
    }
```

Comment: `s/tertiary/ternary` :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Lolz, I was very confident about that :)

Comment: oneliners are <3

Comment: @RonNabuurs Didn't get you! OP has asked for refactoring.

Comment: I like this one. Well, altough it's very different from mine i suppose it still counts as refactorization. I'll vote this as it thaught me something new too. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are only needing the value of your `gender` select for the alert, you could change the value to `Mr.` and `Miss` and just alert/print those.

```
<script>
    "use strict";
    window.onload = function () {
        let form1 = document.getElementById('myForm');
        form1.addEventListener('submit', helloYou);
        function helloYou() {
            let x = document.getElementById("1").value; 
            let a = document.getElementById('3').value;
            alert('Hello ' + a + " " + x + "!");
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        Write your name:
        <input type="text" name="yourname" id="1" placeholder="name">
        <select name="gender" id="3">
            <option value="Mr.">Male</option>
            <option value="Miss">Female</option>
        <input type="submit" name="submission" id="2" value="TRY ME">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function helloYou() {
    const val = id => document.getElementById(id).value; 
    alert(`Hello ${val(3) === "M" ? "Mr." : "Miss"} ${val(1)} !`);
}
```

We can make use of two things 1 tenary to shorten your if logic.

```
condition ? result : otherResult
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

and template literals which let you add javascript to a string `string ${javascript}`` using back tics

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<script>
    "use strict";
    window.onload = function () {
        let form1 = document.getElementById('myForm');
        form1.addEventListener('submit', helloYou);
        function helloYou() {
            let x = document.getElementById("1").value; 
            let a = document.getElementById('3').value;
            let b = "Miss"
            if ( a === "M") {
                b = "Mr.";
            }
            alert('Hello ' + b + " " + x + "!");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this as an option, quite clean :)

```
const helloYou = () => {
  let name = document.getElementById('1').value
  let gender = document.getElementById('3').value
  const prefix = gender === 'M' ? 'Mr.' : 'Miss'
  alert(`Hello ${prefix} ${name}!`)
}
```